# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

I'm pretty sure I already know the answer to this but last year, Stack Exchange ran [Winter Bash 2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/), in which users earned hats which they proudly displayed upon their gravatar. There was a leaderboard of hat earners that looked something like this:

> [image]

Well we have the option to do it again this year!

Here's the rundown:

- Hats are enabled on a per-site basis, if we don't want them we can
  disable them here
- Hats are a fun way to end the year, and they are awesome
- Users can turn off hats on a per-user basis; for those who hate hats you don't have to see everyone else having fun.
- If we choose to accept, the event will run from **15 December 2014** to **4 January 2015**. After the time period, all the hats go away into Last Year's Hat Bin.
- We need to decide if we want hats by **December 1**

Do we like hats or hate hats?

Comment: Ooo, yes we do! I've spent the last 3 days resizing my avatar just to fit the Chuck Yeager helmet.

Comment: So that's why we almost ran out of disk space, @StuartLC!

Comment: YEEEEEEEEES!! More hats! Hats! Hats! Hats!

Comment: Hats are a distraction from the serious business of... uh... Wait, what is the serious thing we do around here?

Comment: See also my [shiny metal hat](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/230513/trashgod).

Comment: **[Trilby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilby)** disappointed by this post...

Comment: I never get any hats so I gonna be scrooge and just say "bah Humbug"

Comment: Please don't turn SO into TF2.

Comment: And what about another joke ? Having every year the same gift might be a little uninteresting...

Comment: I'm saving my answering (and editing) batch for December just because of hats! :)

Comment: I like hats so much, I'm still wearing mine from last year! (Has it really been almost a year already? Crazy.)

Comment: Sure, give me my Santa hat back!

Comment: I think my username answers for me.

Comment: People who opt out of hats should get a _bah humbug_ hat auto-equipped which is visible only to everyone else.

Comment: I want, at least to cover my old bald head.

Comment: I always thought that SO consisted expert and serious people; now when something as simple as hats is brought up, everyone turns into a child. A-aaaaaaand I like it.

Comment: Of course we do!!!

Comment: @bluefeet I voted for you in the mod election this year. Do I get a special hat for that?

Comment: @Boann That'd be favoritism and I hate that!

Comment: @bluefeet It's okay you were only my second choice vote.

Comment: Oooooh! And then we recycle dropped weapons into reclaimed metal, and then we craft this reclaimed metal into hats of our choice, that are not that metally at all! And then we venture out and show off our hats while brutally murdering other people! Oh... oh... oh wait. Wrong place, isn't it? Seriously though. I am in favor of Winter Bash 2014.

Comment: Is that a Cylon hat? Then yes, A million times yes!

Comment: This is all a Gabe Newell conspiracy. He's watching. [See for yourself.](http://www.gabenewell.org)

Comment: yes please.  loved my hats last year.

Comment: I would like to have halloween hats next year.

Comment: No, we _need_ hats.

Comment: If we don't do hats, we'll have to do the safety dance instead...

Comment: Can we have facial hair instead, or as well? Hipster beards, wizard beards, goatees, mirror-universe (evil) goatees, moustaches, mutton-chops...

Comment: @DavidThomas Last year, they did have a mustache with glasses and scarf, so you never know.

Comment: I do not want hats because it encourages artificial behaviour that may or may not be good for the community.

Comment: I read the question title on the side and thought it was about Team Fortress 2.

Comment: Why has @animuson deleted eight of the answers to this question?  In general, they don't seem any more delete-worthy than some of the ones that he/she has allowed to remain here.

Comment: dear @animuson - you are a party pooper. ML is one of my all-time favorite movies.

Comment: I want hats. Just in case they don't get reintroduced this year, I saved a sprite of all of last year's hats so I can wear any of them whenever I want.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277482/4211034, why this answer is deleted? I think I am being misunderstood. :(

Comment: Everyone, that enjoys these stupid hats is just as crazy as I can imagine. But... I _love_ that, and I _love_ all of you hatty freaks. No, SO without hats would certainly be wrong. We're too crazy to live without them...

Comment: I think we should have ascots - then we could have 'Shiny Metal Ascots'!

Comment: 500 views per day! Who said we don't like fun..?

Comment: [status-completed] can be added to this, since there will indeed be hats.

Comment: I would love bugdroid hat!

Answer (score 276, accepted):

We love fun and hats, so yes, I want hats!!

> [image]

The overwhelmingly majority seems to want hats, so **Let there be hats!!**

Comment: Yay! I want bird hats this year.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion [here you go](http://workingwings.com/menagerie/photos/birds/goslingwitch.jpg)

Comment: Yeah, hats[!](http://about:blank)

Comment: Another candidate image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs3aL.jpg

Comment: darn you @MartijnPieters!! Too many choices!!

Comment: @bluefeet: we need a script to rotate between images in a post. *Off to the code mobile!*

Comment: Man browses through `[jquery]` in that hat, people know he's not afraid of anything.

Comment: If a Jayne hat is available, I'll totally vote yes.

Comment: @PaulRichter They'd probably get [in trouble for that](http://www.buzzfeed.com/ellievhall/firefly-hat-triggers-corporate-crackdown)

Comment: @bluefeet Ah crap, forgot about that...

Comment: +1 because I like it. Do we have(or will have) a suggestion topic for hats? I mean, this year has made 20 years from [Senna's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayrton_Senna) passing and - not because I'm a brazilian - I think that would be nice to wear his [helmet](http://formula1collection.com/files/products/21/Senna94A.jpg) this year ;)

Comment: @AirThomas you deserve more upvotes.

Comment: If I wear my hat now. Is that any problem such a limitted usage or else maybe?

Answer (score 136):

YES WE DO!!!!!111!!eleven!

[image]

Comment: I want to upvote for the cute ninja.

Comment: give me hats or give me more hats.  Only options

Comment: Please update your avatar. For happiness. And justice. Think of the unicorns Martijn, think of the unicorns!

Comment: "Have the top-scoring answer on a site meta question with at least 20 upvotes"

Answer (score 130):

I don't care about hats at all, neither do I care about people having "fun" with hats.

What I *do* care about though is people pouring even more crap into SO just to earn some more hats.

Comment: Indeed, if we're going to have hats again, we need to be more careful about what types of requirements there are so that they stop encouraging abusive behavior.

Comment: Your just hatin cause you didn't get hats last year (I'm guessing)

Comment: @iamkrillin ... or maybe PeeHaa is just genuinely concerned about the current quality of the content on SO and believes that another incentive would simply increase the gamification of the site, further plummeting its already-lacking quality.

Comment: @swasheck nah, can't be it.

Comment: I'd like to point out that gamification was a design goal for stackoverflow. http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-gamification/

Comment: He who-removes hats is boring, though. Have a bit of fun @PeeHaa :P

Comment: @iamkrillin So **all** gamification is good? Or do you think it's possible that some gamification is awesome and some gamification is completely undesirable?

Comment: @iamkrillin i understand that. however, even good things, taken to an extreme, can become bad things. pain-killers. sugar. alcohol. risk-taking. etc.

Comment: Joking aside, this is a valid concern. Didn't see *too much* craziness on SO last year, but there were a few cases of abuse (including one guy who completely wrecked his formerly-in-good-standing account in pursuit of hats). Outside of SO, there was one site where some of the *top users* put together a voting ring and essentially trolled other sites for hats. All of that really takes away from *intended* feeling of lighthearted enjoyment; we would do well to keep a close watch for such things this year.

Comment: The point is that gamification encourages behavior. We just want to make sure it's the right behavior.

Comment: @Shog9 Well most of the mods were pretty much saying that the flag queue was more or less useless for many days a result of floods of improper flags, since there was a hat for flagging.  Many review queues also got a flood of crap (and thanks to crappy reviewers, many of *these* were getting rubber stamped) for the same reason.  Unless that was the year before, I forget.

Comment: @Shog: Woah I never heard about a voting ring. Do you have more stories to share?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe there was a user on English.SE that [set up a question asking for the etymology of "Marauder"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142142/whats-a-marauder) (now deleted) and the OP took turns changing the accepted answer to low-vote answers (to award the ["checkmark-stealing" Marauder hat](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/marauder)). A lot of the low-vote answers were pretty funny, but it was certainly less-than-appropriate behavior. Also, [this Meta.English.SE post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4356/21286).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Found an archived copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20131225055605/http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142142/what-is-a-marauder

Comment: This. If this answer hat a meme picture, it would most likely get more upvotes. Something like a picture of George Washington saying: Not Everything You Read on Internet is Truth. ~Abraham Lincoln 2001

Comment: @apsillers: Oh, my. And a number of those involved are people with whom I've had "unfortunate" dealings on English.SE; surprise, surprise! Thanks for the info — I don't know how I missed this at the time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm glad it wasn't just me.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Nah it's not. I'm spending more and more time on E.SE lately and at the same time regretting it more and more.

Comment: Someone suggested me to read this, probably assuming I didn't already. So now I would ask... Is this reply pro hats, against hats or just pointing out something I would hope no one wants- more bad content? Forgive me PeeHaa, but I don't get what you propose to do. Are you trying to tell me that it's better to not have hat to avoid people misbehaving? Fine for me if the community prefer it this way but I would say that then you will punish the context instead of the behaviour.

Comment: If you are going to game the system for hats, probably you will try to game it for repz or badges to. Should we remove bounties because a few users systematically downvote opposing answers? I agree on the need to keep an open eyes around, but I don't think one should go to the extreme of removing hats to correct the behaviour of an handful of genius that will probably find other ways to hurt SE. I was a seer once. We never though of removing pvp zones because pk where using bugs to kill new pgs. We just showed them the door.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist, I think the idea is that gaming the system is significantly more feasible in the short run, and hats are only around for a short duration so they incentivize short-term behaviors.

Comment: IMO the [secret hats are particularly conducive to counterproductive and random behaviour](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214869/149333) in trying to unlock them ... some hats should be hard to get no doubt, but the mechanism for obtaining them always be made known?

Comment: Yeah, I do remember that @Servy - the 10K flag queue was a big contributing factor there, and solidified our suspicions that it was [fundamentally broken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue). Even without that though, extrinsic rewards for flagging are kinda sketchy.

Answer (score 40):

Yes!!! of course I want hat.

[image]

Comment: This post is about hats, not about cats ;)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Oh you are here also :P.. */me hides*

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Don't worry the cat has a hat on :)

Comment: We want cats in hats!!! I hope that's not a copyright violation :/

Comment: IM A CAAAAAAAAT

Comment: @bjb568 Hmm. Don't you want hat ? I thought you want this is why I posted nice gif :D

Comment: Me want hat! Cat want hat!

Comment: Wow! That hat has a cat!

Answer (score 34):

Literally, can't wait....I'm all ready ;)

[image]

Comment: I particularly like how even his hair was lightened by being under a hat.

Answer (score 24):

[image]

Comment: Alright, you got me with this one.  Nice!!  But remember they **will** take away the hats after **4 January 2015**.

Comment: @bluefeet - Not if I place them all over my gravatar :P

Comment: what you mean ... fake? I was planning to exchange them into [those](http://36.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9ia40umQp1rwsqbxo1_1280.png) later on ...

Comment: Could we get a Braveheart hat? Some blue face paint?

Answer (score 21):

**No**, we are serious programmers and we hate hats!!

> [image]

Comment: I want to upvote for the picture...

Comment: There better be a hat of him this year.

Comment: @Servy [Like this](http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQUxIltjEG_dx2LW6TtkeOJslCpzGWZyVXJ_K_X_6-MHVIz-PS4w)?

Comment: @bluefeet Now I know what I'm getting for Christmas this year.

Comment: Happy to help, @Servy

Comment: Damn, its very funny, but I WANT HATZ!!! What to do, upvote or downvote?

Comment: "Post an answer with a -20 or lower net score and at least 20 upvotes on your site meta"?

Comment: What does serious programmers wear? http://www.codethinked.com/the-programmer-dress-code

Comment: I think we should have ascots - then we could have 'Shiny Metal Ascots'! –

Answer (score 10):

As my image states quite unambiguously, I like my current hat well enough.

Comment: HEISENBERG!!!!!

Answer (score 8):

I think that most of us want to:

[image: Keep Calm and Wear a Hat]

<sub><sub>Made on the [(Keep-Calm-O-Matic)](http://www.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/p/keep-calm-and-wear-a-hat-76/)</sub></sub>

Comment: I want the Boba Fett one!

Comment: I wore the orange upvote arrow hat last year, it was my favorite :D

Answer (score 7):

What about the hats we unlocked last year; do we get them back? Or shall we unlock them again?

Is this a new hat collection or the same as last year?

I liked the idea, so I'm for it :D

Comment: We don't have any real details...yet. You'll have to wait and be surprised!!

Comment: I'll wait to be surprised then :D

Comment: Like the last year, the hat collection will probably reset from the previous Winterbash.

Comment: No goofy gif? No upvote! *waves index finger with head to one side and eyes closed*

Answer (score 6):

It came without ribbons.
It came without [***HATS***].
It came without packages, boxes, or bags.

Maybe Stack Overflow, he thought, doesn't need this bore.
*Maybe* Stack Overflow, perhaps means a little bit more.

*-adapted from Dr. Seuss*

No - we don't need hats!

Comment: @Bradley but question was if one wants hatz. Why can't disagreement be expressed?

Comment: You're a mean one, Mr. @ChiefTwoPencils

Answer (score 3):

## YES!

---

[image: moar moar moar moar moar]

moar plz

Comment: Ermahgerd Herts!

Comment: It looks so elegant :D

Answer (score 1):

If we have to have hats, can we please make sure that all the hats are appropriate for the site that issues them?

In December 2012, I posted an answer on a Stack Exchange site (not Stack Overflow) and earned a hat that was culturally inappropriate for the site, and slightly offensive in the context in which it was issued.  I was a little upset by this, and was relieved that in 2013, I was able to opt out of having hats.

I wouldn't mind opting in to hats for 2014, if I knew that each site would only issue hats that were appropriate for that site.

Comment: It's impossible to be sure that a hat won't offend or conflict with someone. It's entirely possible that the entire concept of disposable hats would be considered anathema to [some folks](http://meta.sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/218/poll-should-sustainability-se-participate-in-the-2014-winter-bash-holiday-hat). Doing this right would mean a custom set of hats for each site - which would be *awesome*, but also entirely too much work.

Comment: Sure, @Shog9, I guess you're right.  I was about to suggest that the community of each site as a whole could be given the option of having hats on the site.  Then I realised that this is meta.stackoverflow, not meta.SE; so this is exactly what The Powers That Be are doing.  Moreover, when this same question was asked, approximately a year ago, on the meta of the site that issued the offending hat, there was no objection at all (although there would have been if I had seen the meta-question at the time).  So I guess my view must be the minority - it wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: @Shog9 that said, I guess that hats like "The Stallman" could be more likely be misinterpreted than for example a cupcake.

Comment: The cupcake was made with lard, @SPArchaeologist. It was *super-inappropriate* for lots of folks.

Answer (score 0):

Bring back hats for the end of this year!

Just be careful if you create the Peahat:

[image: Zelda's Peahat]

I will be tempted to wait for the wearer to stop moving so I can use <s>wield my Magical Sword</s> smash it with my Dupe Hammer.

[image]

Comment: Also beware of pee hats.

Comment: @JasonC Urine trouble when you get one of those.

Answer (score 0):

I presume all the nay-sayers here wont be wearing theirs this chrimbo then?

[image]

Answer (score -4):

I personally do not want to see hats on SO. The reason is that these hats, while fun and encouraging for some users, are probably a detriment to the overall quality of the website.

Consider that people will do things to get these hats, at almost any cost. Will it change the way people answer questions? I think it will, but most likely it will only encourage less active people to become more active. This would be great, but hats are the wrong motivation.

It's similar to video games which offer achievements or even hats (TF2). You typically have to do something in the video game (kill players with a knife 1000 times and earn an assassin hood) and causes people to seek out the reward by repetition or lots of attempts. I suspect this would apply and result in people essentially spamming low quality posts. This not only lowers the quality of the content but imposes a burden on those of us that push through the review queue which is already out of control.

I believe that if you're going to allow us to disable hats, that it should be the default. Additionally, users should have a second option, disabled by default, to not show questions and answers by people with hats enabled.

I say no hats because this is a professional Q&A forum, not TF2 or something equally absurd. However, if a movement for monacles comes about, I am all for it.

Comment: for me the challenge is to see how many I can actually get without pushing the limits. Just be myself, do what I normally do and see how rewarding in terms of hats that is going to be.

Comment: And that *"I believe that if you're going to allow us to disable hats, that it should be the default. Additionally, users should have a second option, disabled by default, to not show questions and answers by people with hats enabled."* gets you my -1 as completely irrational.

Comment: @vba4all If most people had the approach you do for the hats, I would be more accepting of hats. As far as your comment about me being irrational, I should probably explain myself. I think that if people are going to be potentially submitting low quality content because of their need for hats, that I don't want to see that content. The reason people should have to enable the hat rewards on their end is because that will tell you who is actively pursuing hats and keeps the rest of us out of it. It lets me discriminate against the content I want to see as well.

Comment: Agree with @vba4all. I'm not going to make a post I wouldn't otherwise just to get a hat. Its just a fun reward for doing what I already do. Bad users will post bad content, good users will post good content. Perhaps we should just put a rep restriction on the feature (100+?) so that people that *do* post crap aren't incentivized.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET A lot of people post pretty bad content or even spam with 100 reputation. The problem isn't the good users and it's not the continuously bad ones either. It's the people that get pushed over that very fine line by an incentive such as hats. I'm not saying it's going to cause mass hysteria and everyone is going to trample people like they do in Walmart on black Friday, but I'll wager that it does in fact shift the overall quality during the period they first come out. We should record some stats on it, or get some from last year.

Comment: Hats may bring "additional" potential for bad behaviour, but those who post crap to get hats would surely have otherwise posted crap elsewhere to get some badge or rep anyway? Besides, we cannot let less savoury users stop us having fun. I'm confident Stack are putting in good measures to stop evil shenanigans best they can.

Answer (score -11):

```
Infinite(Yes ... Yes ... Yes ...)
```

[image]

Wish we could keep them permanently or at least for the entire year.

Comment: Then they wouldn't be special any more, Rahul.

Comment: Christmas already starts way too early, like late October with Christmas things in stores. If we did festive things all year it wouldn't be festive or Christmas, it would just "be".