# What happened to all the hats?

Tags: discussion

So what happened to all the hats?

They've disappeared all of a sudden![image]

Answer (score 4):

They're appearing (and can be achieved) only for the limited time of the yearly *winter bash hat competition*

Also see the mentioned time perionds in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277407/do-we-want-hats) please.

Comment: Hey could you remove your answer, so I can delete the question. Yes, it is a duplicate after all.

Comment: Thanks!           ..........

Comment: @Steve _"Hey could you remove your answer, so I can delete the question."_ Nope! Take care what you're asking, and research beforehand :-P ...

Comment: ok..... Do downvotes here effect my stackoverflow reputation?

Comment: @Steve _" Do downvotes here effect my stackoverflow reputation?"_ No, they don't (as you should have noticed. Not directly at least).

Comment: Yes I have noticed.

Comment: That's interesting..

Comment: @Steve Take care of the meta effect when exposing yourself, but usually downvotes here means just disagreement for asking an invalid or otherwise trivially to solve question. Other as with the main site, you're not paying any rep asking such here.